# In PHP what does |= mean, That is pipe equals (not exclamation)

Tags: php

I just found this in some code and I can't find anything on the web or php manual. Most likely since its an irregular character.

Here is one of the lines that uses it.

```
$showPlayer |= isset($params['node']) && $params['node'];
```

Comment: It's shorthand for `$showPlayer =  $showPlayer | (isset($params['node']) && $params['node']);`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`|=` is to `|` as `+=` is to `+`; that is, `$a |= $b;` is the same as `$a = $a | $b;`. The `|` operator is [the bitwise OR operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: Thanks. It seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 5):

Or-Equals.  Similar to saying $var += 2, or $var = $var + 2.  In this case, it's `$showPlayer = $showPlayer | isset....`