# How "|=" PHP Operator work?

Tags: php

I have seen this code in a source:

```
$value = 10;
$value |= 9;
echo $value;
```

and I get : 11

I still don't understand how it works

> $value |= 9;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP what does |= mean, That is pipe equals (not exclamation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142091/in-php-what-does-mean-that-is-pipe-equals-not-exclamation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$value |= 9;
```

is

```
$value = 9 | $value;
```

which is

```
$value = 9 | 10;
```

and | is the bitwise or operator(1|0 is 1, 1|0 is 1, everything else is 0): http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php, so you have:

```
$value = 00001001 | 00001010;
```

and that gives

```
$value = 00001011;
```

which is 11

Comment: Thank you, I understant it :D

Answer (score 0):

`|` is the logical OR operator.

10 in binary is `1010`, 9 is `1001` so if you run the logical OR operator over them you get `1011` which is 11.