# Why image file can't deleted from uploaded folder

Tags: php

I tried the following code to delete image file from uploaded folder

```
public function delete(){

                $query = 'SELECT  *  FROM  tbl_product  WHERE  productID= ' . $this->productID;

                $STH = $this->DBH->query($query);

                $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                $img = $STH->fetch();

                foreach($deleteIMG = $img){
                    {
                        $deleteLINK = $deleteIMG['image'];
                        unlink("../resource/image/".$deleteLINK);
                    }
                }

                $sql= "DELETE FROM tbl_product WHERE productID=" . $this->productID;

                $result = $this->DBH->exec($sql);
```

Here can't delete image file from uploaded folder but data can be deleted from database.

So pls help me anyone in proper soloution.
Thanks....

Comment: Check if the images files have a writable permissions

Comment: You need to check file permission and also use php function for file existance

Comment: how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing the details of your server. It's likely a permissions issue. You can use `ls -al` to check permissions.

There are two things to consider: permissions and file/directory ownership. Your web server user should have owner or group ownership. You need `write and execute` permissions on the file and its parent directory to be able to delete a file. This page does a pretty decent job of explaining it (if using Linux): https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions

As far as your code goes, you can make it 'all or nothing'. Meaning that if the files don't delete, the records don't delete from the database either. The `unlink()` function returns boolean false if it doesn't successfully delete the file. Try something like this:

```
$allDeleted = true;

foreach($images as $img) {
   $deleteLINK = $deleteIMG['image'];
   $allDeleted |= unlink("../resource/image/" . $deleteLINK);
}

if ($allDeleted === true) {
   $sql= "DELETE FROM tbl_product WHERE productID=" . $this->productID;
   $result = $this->DBH->exec($sql);
}
```

The `|=` is the bitwise OR operator. This post does a good job of explaining it:

[In PHP what does |= mean, That is pipe equals (not exclamation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142091/in-php-what-does-mean-that-is-pipe-equals-not-exclamation)

Answer (score 0):

@Zunaid, this is how I'm able to delete both a file (whether image, video, document, etc.) from a folder AND its' filepath from the db table at the same time (code written hours ago & **ruthlessly tested**);

```
Code Breakdown:

<?php
// triggered by a link on the delete form - 
// < a href="delete.php?fname=<?php echo $fname; ? >" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirm('you sure about this?');"><i class="icon-trash icon-white">< /a >
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{

   //include the database connection file
   include("db.php");


   //instantiate the PHP Data Object
   $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password, $db_options);


   // set the PDO error mode to exception
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


   //get the filename
   $fname = $_GET['fname'];


   //delete file from directory with checking for both file_exists AND is_writable
   if(file_exists($fname) && !is_writable($fname))
   {
   chown($fname, 0644); // tried CHMOD - didn't work - LAST RESORT USAGE FOR CHOWN: 0777 - USE WITH CARE!!!      
   }       
   unlink("user_data/$uname".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$fname);


   //deleting the row from table
   $sql = "DELETE FROM `upload_data` WHERE `FILE_NAME`=:FILE_NAME";
   $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute(array(':FILE_NAME' => $fname));


   if($query)
   {
      echo "<h4 style='color:red'>File DELETED</h4>";
      header('Refresh: 1;url=home.php');
   }
   else
   {
      echo "<h4 style='color:red'>Error Deleting File</h4>";
      header('Refresh: 1;url=home.php');
   }

}
?>
```

I, myself, pored over **dozens** of Stack Overflow questions/answers and full-length web tutorials before I was able to craft this for my own situation.

I was having the **EXACT** same problem of being able to remove the file path from the db table, without the code even touching the file. Hope you can twist this to your own ends...